# How do you properly define a statically inherited method?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I am trying to implement an inheritance chain whereby methods declared on the base type return the derived type *by value*.  For example, I have a base class `Base` with a method `func()`.  On a derived class `Derived`, I want `func()` to return an instance of `Derived` by value.

To do this, I am trying to use ["static polymorphism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern): the base class takes the derived class via a template parameter, and then makes the method return the template type.  Here is my header file:

```
#pragma once

template<typename Derived>
class Base {
  public:
    Derived func() const;
};

class DerivedA : public Base<DerivedA> {
  public:
    DerivedA() : Base() {}
    DerivedA(const Base<DerivedA>& other) : Base(other) {}
};
```

So far so good.  I define the function in a cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Derived>
Derived Base<Derived>::func() const {
    std::cout << "Calling func" << std::endl;
    return Derived(*this);
}
```

And then I call it in a main function:

```
#include "demo.h"

int main() {
    DerivedA a;
    a.func();
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately, compiling this code results in the following linker error.

```
main.cpp.o: In function `main': main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `Base<DerivedA>::func() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(demo)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp demo.cpp demo.h)
add_executable(demo ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Oddly, if I move the definition into the header file, the code compiles without the linker error.

How do I properly define the function (ideally in a cpp file) and make the linker error go away?